# What is the regex that matches all syntactic names in R

Tags: r, regex, syntax

From `?make.names`

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number.

How can we match this using regex ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `^[[:alpha:].](?!\\d)[\w.]*$`?

Comment: Wiktor almost! except your solution dismisses foreign letters

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl compatible regex,  :

- Consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters : `(\d|\p{L}|\.|\_)*`
- Starts with a letter : `^\p{L}`
- Or the dot not followed by a number : `^\.(\p{L}|\.|\_)`, or just the dot alone

We want to include backticked names, they can contain anything except backticks : `` [^`]+ ``

Putting it all together :

```r
pattern1 <- "(^(\\p{L}|(\\.(\\p{L}|\\.|\\_)))(\\d|\\p{L}|\\.|\\_)*$)|(^\\.$)"
pattern2 <- "(^(\\p{L}|(\\.(\\p{L}|\\.|\\_)))(\\d|\\p{L}|\\.|\\_)*$)|(^\\.$)|(^`[^`]+`$)"
test <- c(".", "good", "good1", "g.o_öd", ".good", "`good?`", ".1bad", "1bad", "b-a-d", "`b`a`d`")
setNames(grepl(pattern1, test, perl = TRUE), test)
#>       .    good   good1  g.o_öd   .good `good?`   .1bad    1bad   b-a-d `b`a`d` 
#>    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
setNames(grepl(pattern2, test, perl = TRUE), test)
#>       .    good   good1  g.o_öd   .good `good?`   .1bad    1bad   b-a-d `b`a`d` 
#>    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>